# Pyomo - using gurobi persistent solver to solve subproblems in parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, pyomo

I am trying to solve a MILP with Benders Decomposition using Pyomo.

The model is divided up into a master problem and many sub problems.
Later, I want to solve all sub problems in parallel and I found a promising example [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/main/examples/pyomo/benders/runbenders).

I want to use gurobi_persistent to solve the model since I need to utilize some of its functions in scripting. I have problems to implement the .set_instance(model) function, which would normaly works like this:

```
solver = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
solver.set_instance(model)
solver.solve(tee=True)
```

Comming back to the Benders example I tried to implement the set.instance(model) together with  function with SolverManagerFactory as followed, but i got an Error.

```
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory("serial")
solver_manager.set_instance(model)
solve_all_instances(solver_manager, 'gurobi_persistent', model)
```

*Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'SolverManager_Serial' object has no attribute 'set_instance'*

Clearly SolverManagerFactory does not have this this function. Then I tried the following:

```
solver = pe.SolverFactory('gurobi_persistent')
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory("serial")
instance_model= solver.set_instance(model)
solve_all_instances(solver_manager, 'gurobi_persistent', instance_model)
```

*Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not iterable*

So, any help on how to use Gurobi Persistent with SolverManagerFactory would be really appreciated! Also any suggestions on documentation of SolverManagerFactory would be intresting.
Thanks a lot!